# Weird Apache error - Apache hangs & needs restarting regularly

Tags: apache-http-server, php, top, httpd

I've been recently receiving this weird error where Apache just becomes unresponsive and completely stops until it is manually restarted.

It gets to a point where I can not longer retrieve apache status from cPanel, and all websites running apache just hang on "connecting" until it times out.

Has anyone else received this problem?

This is a screenshot of my top when this weird problem occurs, usually the top has all httpd and php processes. 
[image: weird]
Thanks for your help

Comment: are you running/hosting any memory intensive scripts?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
It was related to mod_fcgid's bug of locking processes and then slowly killing apache completely.

Listed here is [how I fixed it](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/apache-graceful-restarts-fastcgi-mod_fcgid-cant-lock-process-table-pid-151373-p4.html#post1170461)